# creating custom event / signal on cocoa os x

Tags: cocoa, macos, events, multithreading, signals

I am not much familiar with developing application using cocoa on mac. Can some one help me with how can i create custom events or signals, and how to make sure thread acts when these are generated or triggered.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with custom events/signals? There may be a totally different way to achieve what you want to do. I guess by `signal` you mean UNIX signals, but what do you mean technically by `events`?

Comment: I want asynchronous notifications mechanism. 
Want to know how I can create/send/receive and react on these notifications (events)

Comment: Found the way to send/receive notification you can refer to http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to register/send/receive notification. you can write logic to react on these events. More info can be found at: [Notification programming guide for cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i)